# QTableView, ширина столбцов, как задать?

Tags: qt, c++

[image]

Как задать, чтобы первый столбец автоматически заполнял всю ширину таблицы, а второй принимал ширину содержимого?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(/*номер столбца*/, QHeaderView::Stretch);`

И все дела...